# Problem with display of hyperlinks on Image within DIV tag

Tags: css, hyperlink, background-image

I'm trying to display text(hyperlinks) over an image; I have written the following code snippets that doesn't do what I want to do (in the .css file).

```
#menu-bar
 {
 padding: 10px 0px auto 0px;
 height:auto;
 width: 1000px;
 float:left;
 margin: 10px 0px auto 0px; 
 background:url(/images/bar_full_3_1.jpg) repeat-x;
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id ="menu-bar">
    file | open | edit | ...

 </div>
```

this code display IMAGE in IDE ONLY but doesn't display it in BROWSER.
Thanks!!

NOW THIS PROBLEM HAS SOLVED: THE MISTAKE I MADE ARE AS FOLLOWS:
-> Incorrect syntax- used commas while giving values to attribute.
-> incorrect path/url

Comment: Is this some new HTML & CSS or what?

Comment: CSS doesnt have commas between values. Try removing all commas from your CSS file.

Comment: check the path to image, in CSS the image has to be relative to the CSS file itself.. if in doubt use an absolute path and see if that works.. but do amend the CSS to remove the commas first too (replace them with a space) ;0

Comment: actually i have just started to use CSS for first time that is why such mistake creep in.. well thanks all of you.. I have got my output running beautifuly.. :)

Comment: **UPDATE** ...This time output is visible is in IDE (vs 2008) but iimage is still not visible in browser(menu item can be read). What should I do now?

Comment: again, my guess is that the path to your image is incorrect when being viewed in your browser. Look at the path and make sure it's correct, relative to the place you're opening up the page in the browser.

Comment: Thank's jamie for taking time here... actually I restarted my Browser my and IDE; after which the code ran smoothly. thanks again. :)

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted in that case ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If your CSS file is in a folder like "styles" then you'll need to jump out of that folder in your background image url:

```
background: #0066FF url(../images/bar_full_3_1.jpg) repeat-x;
```

(notice the ../ before the images folder).

This is the most common cause of images not displaying.

**UPDATE**

It's also worth noting, as pointed out in the comments here, that you've got a couple of mistakes in your CSS code. Firstly you needn't use a comma to seperate property values. A single space is all that's required.

Also make sure you get the order of your property values correct.

Comment: I just coppied his CSS. I'll ammend it now. I think the overall answer is going to be more useful to him than just tidying up his CSS though.

Comment: Did that and removed the comments ;-)

Comment: Yes, i have removed all the comments.